# Merge two jQuery Function

Tags: jquery

I have two functions that pulling some of content from html and returning it in body.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var b = [];
    $('.avatar_ name').each(function(i,e) {
        b[i] = $(this).text();
    });

    $('body').empty();
    for (var i = 0, j = b.length; i < j; i++) {
        $('body').append( b[i] + '<br>');
    } 


});
(document).ready(function() {
 var a = [];
    $('a.avatar_user').each(function(i,e) {
        a[i] = $(this).attr('href');
    });

    $('body').empty();
    for (var i = 0, j = a.length; i < j; i++) {
        $('body').append( a[i] + '<br>');
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do as a result is to merge those two functions together and as a result get this:

```
$('body').append( a[i] + b[i] + '<br>');
```

Any Help much appreciated

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ready(fn)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready) is a special function in `JQuery` that can be written in one or many blocks. If written in many blocks, each block can not access others variables.
In your case it's better to write a single function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var a = [];
    var b = [];

    $('a.avatar_user').each(function(i,e) {
        a[i] = $(this).attr('href');
    });

    $('.avatar_ name').each(function(i,e) {
        b[i] = $(this).text();
    });

    $('body').empty();
    for (var i = 0, j = a.length; i < j; i++) {
        $('body').append( a[i] + b[i] + '<br>');
    } 
});
```

(if the 2 arrays have different length, you can add a check before appending to bdy)